# Stopping Express server

Tags: gruntjs, angular-fullstack

I'm using angular-fullstack generator, while grunt serve, express server stop suddenly after few seconds, and this error occurred:

```
Running "wait" task
Waiting for server reload...
finished populating users
SocketIO / [127.0.0.1:51714] CONNECTED
Done waiting!

Running "open:server" (open) task

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
SocketIO / [127.0.0.1:51714] CONNECTED
SocketIO / [127.0.0.1:51731] CONNECTED
getSetting res : { homeSlides: [], __v: 0, _id: 5739f8b826dd0be8189259f1 }
Stopping Express server


Execution Time (2016-05-27 10:37:32 UTC)
concurrent:server  5.8s  ██ 3%
express:dev        2.4s  █ 1%
Total 2m 48.3s


Process finished with exit code 0
```

when I run **grunt** it shows:

```
Done, without errors
```

I'm stuck on it, Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this on Node.js Version: v8.2.1.
Solved by installing version v6.11.2.

I was stuck on same error for few hours but then downgraded my Node version and removed node_modules folder and run **npm install** in your project.